# How to get the cell value from another sheet using vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am working on Excel vba i've a set of columns retrived from sql into excel using vba and i've to get the id of the particular retrived column value by referring another sheet. For example i've 2 sheets where sheet1 has rid,rname columns and sheet2 has sid,rid,date columns.whereas, The values retrived from sql to excel sheet2 has sid,rname,date values i want to replace rname value with rid value by referring corresponding rid in sheet1. How to do this using VBA code

Comment: is this VBA, VB6, VBScript or VB.NET. These are not the same things

Comment: Further, this isn't a free code service. show us what you've tried or found through research

Comment: Don't tag-spam please. Use only the tags relevant to your question.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response noted the above comments.I have tried find option in the sheet1 where rname is passed as the key for search Cells.Find(What:="rname", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=false).Select

Comment: remove the `"` around `"rname"` - this will force it to search for the literal string `rname` and not the value of the variable `rname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider all comments under your question for further posts.
Here is an answer nevertheless.

This works for two columns with the same amount of rows:

```
Sub stack()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim targetRng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)

Set targetRng = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(firstRow, columnID), ws2.Cells(lastRow, columnID))
i = firstRowSourceSheet

For Each cell In targetRng
cell.Value = ws1.Cells(i, columnIDSource)
i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Fill in variables accordingly.